# ag-grid angular 2 header template

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I wrapped ag-grid in a ng2 component.

and I want the first header to be a checkbox with the parent functionality.

how can I do it from the container component?

**ag-grid.component**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'rg-grid',
  templateUrl: 'grid-control.component.html',
  directives: [AgGridNg2]
})

export class RgGridComponent {

  private gridOptions: GridOptions;
  private showGrid: boolean;

  @Input() rowData: any[];
  @Input() columnDefs: AbstractColDef[];
}
```

**container component**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'alerts-table',
    templateUrl: 'alertsTable.component.html',
    directives: [RgGridComponent]
})

export class AlertsTableComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedAlert: IAlert;
    users: User[];
    checkedAlerts : IAlert[];
    displayDialog : boolean;
    dialogContent : string;
    columns : ColDef[];

    constructor(private _alertsService: AlertsService, private _usersService: UsersService) {
        this.displayDialog = false;
        this.investigationRequest = new EventEmitter<number>();
        this.columns = [ ??? ] 
        this.checkedAlerts = new Array<Alert>();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ag-Grid doesn't support Angular 2 components in the headers. it is something we are working on right now and hope to have it in a release three weeks from now. it will probably be v8.0.0 (we will be pushing out v7.2.0 this week, then the next major version will have the new headers).

Comment: Thanks Niall you're the best!